# Android incoming http request port redirection

Tags: android, http, webserver, robotics

The are some lego robots managed by arm structures, with established http connection on the port 80. There is a communication webserver running on a rooted android device using the  port 8080.

Can I forward incoming http requests from 80 to 8080?

Comment: On a rooted device you should be able to

Comment: I tried some solutions provided by programmers at google play, they work well only on port 8080.